# REST web service to interface with a customer database

Tags: java, database, rest, jpa, jersey

In what ways could I improve this? Does it look good? Any security concerns? I am using Jersey, Jackson and JPA. What about the architecture? I basically have `CustomerResource` communicating with `CustomerService` and `CustomerService` Communicates with the Entity. The `updateCustomer` method is in `CustomerResource`. I am absolutely confused on how to do the `updateCustomer` request, even after looking at several resources.

This is my second web service using Jersey and the first one didn't use JPA and Jackson.

```
@Path("/customers")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomerResource {

    private CustomerService custService;

    public CustomerResource() {
        this.custService = new CustomerService();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response getCustomerId(@PathParam("id") String customerId) {
        try {
            Customer customer = custService.findById(Integer.parseInt(customerId));
            if (customer == null) {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("The following id wasn't found: " + customerId)
                        .build();
            }
            return Response.ok(customer).build();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.SEE_OTHER)
                    .entity("You must enter a number ------   Error  -----     : " + customerId
                            + "\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                            + e.getMessage())
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response updateCustomer(String body, @PathParam("id") String customerId) {


        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("body = " + body).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response deleteCustomer(@PathParam("id") String customerId) {
        Customer customer = custService.findById(Integer.parseInt(customerId));
        custService.delete(customer);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("")
    public Response createCustomer(String body) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<Customer> customers = mapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<List<Customer>>() {
            });
            for (Customer customer : customers) {
                custService.create(customer);
            }
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .entity("An error occurred will parsing the JSON! Please double check the format of the JSON."
                            + "\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                            + e.getMessage())
                    .build();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("")
    public Response searchCustomer(@QueryParam("address") String address, @QueryParam("phoneNum") String phoneNum) {
        List<Customer> customers;
        if (phoneNum != null) {
            customers = custService.findByPhoneNum(phoneNum);
        } else if (address != null) {
            customers = custService.findByAddress(address);
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("You must use the correct URL pattern.").build();
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(customers).build();
    }
}
```

Service Layer

```
public class CustomerService extends GenericService<Customer, Integer>{

    public CustomerService() {
        super(Customer.class);
    }

    public List<Customer> findByAddress(String address) {
         TypedQuery<Customer> query =
                 super.getManager().createNamedQuery("Customer.findByAddress", Customer.class);
         query.setParameter("address", address);
         return query.getResultList();
    }

    public List<Customer> findByPhoneNum(String phoneNum) {
         TypedQuery<Customer> query =
                 super.getManager().createNamedQuery("Customer.findByPhoneNum", Customer.class);
         query.setParameter("phoneNum", phoneNum);
         return query.getResultList();
    }
}

public abstract class GenericService<T, Id> {

    private EntityManager manager;

    private final Class<T> entityType;

    public GenericService(Class<T> entityType) {
        manager = DatabaseUtil.getSessionFactory().createEntityManager();
        this.entityType = entityType;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        manager.close();
    }

    public void update(T entity) {
        manager.merge(entity);
    }

    public void create(T entity) {
        manager.persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        manager.remove(entity);
    }

    public T findById(Id id) {
        return manager.find(entityType, id);
    }

    protected void beginTransaction() {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    protected void saveChanges() {
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    protected EntityManager getManager() {
        return this.manager;
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Customer.findByAddress",
                query="SELECT * FROM Customers c where c.address = :address"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Customer.findByPhoneNum",
                query="SELECT * FROM Customers c where c.phoneNum = :phoneNum")
})
public class Customer {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNum;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNum() {
        return phoneNum;
    }

    public void setPhoneNum(String phoneNum) {
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code work? You said it is "hardly tested" so it is not clear.

Comment: yes I tested with postman some but not extensively....

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. You may want to edit your post to clarify that.

Comment: so I will take it as the REST web service looks good.

Comment: Code looks fine. If you worry about architecture, security or just not sure about your project structure - I would say go for Jhipster (http://www.jhipster.tech/) - it generates typical project with best practices. So you might place your code into it. It generates entity classes, dao, unit tests.